# How to use variable/prop in ternary operator

Tags: reactjs

This component renders nicely:

```
const Footer = () => {
  let dataDiv = <div>Data is: Some data</div>;
  return (
    <div>
      {data ? dataDiv : ''}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But if I change the text "some data" with a variable, then the html inside dataDiv is not rendered normally, but as pure text:

```
const Footer = () => {
  let data = 'Some data';
  let dataDiv = <div>Data is: {data}</div>;
  return (
    <div>
      {data ? dataDiv : ''}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have many different data properties that I want to show or hide depending if it is present or not, how can I solve this in React in a nice way?

Comment: I just tested your 2º code and it works okay, what version of React are you using?

Comment: I just tested it as well and everything works fine. I made a fiddle for it: https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/

Comment: In fact, the first one is not working hehe

Comment: Hmm, I do not understand, now it is working... Thanks for input, guys, I thought I did it the wrong way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid syntax and works fine, however a few things to help clean it up.

First, I would recommend is when you plan to use something as a Boolean value use the !! (not not) operator to ensure its a boolean.
Second, I'd recommend you return `null` instead of an empty string in the render method as this wont render anything in the DOM.

Third, since you are using ES6 arrow function syntax you can use template literals for strings.

```
const Footer = () => {
  let data = 'Some data';
  let dataDiv = <div>{`Data is: ${data}`}</div>;
  return (
    <div>
      {!!data ? dataDiv : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for tips on cleaning up the code. But what is reasons for what you suggest? The advantage using `Boolean()`? The advantage of using `null`? And why using the ES6 template strings when the "pure JSX" is shorter?

Comment: And one more thing: Is using `&&` perhaps better than using ternary? `Boolean(data) && dataDiv`

Comment: The template strings can prevent more than one span element that react will auto create. Boolean is a preferred and best practice when ensuring a boolean type check. And null is the react preferred default

Answer (score 0):

Related, here's a use of ternary and spread for (boolean) props

`<Component {... a ? { b: 1 } : { c: 1 } } />`

to avoid using ternary in components, which can in some cases prevent code repetition.